# Getting SecurityException on my signed java applet

Tags: java, html

I am getting a `SecurityException` on an applet that does not do anything (empty applet).

The code for the embedding is:

```
<applet code="Screenshot" archive="file:\\\<?php echo URLgenerator::getScryptURL('screenshot.jar'); ?>" width="100px" height="100px">
</applet>
```

I thought before that it because I didn't sign it, but I did using the keytool and the jarsigner but it did not help. What is the problem?

Comment: I might jump into this once you have responded to my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324647/securityexception-on-my-java-applet#comment-11777293) and I see some HTML that does *not* have an `archive` attribute that points to a a file!